# RWD: Show Desktop version in mobile minified, without horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Maybe my question will be somehow odd but my client wants to remove responsiveness for some time from the site, and see desktop version in mobile.

First I've removed responsive meta tag, but get horizontal scrolls in page. What I want is to see my website on iPhone as I see it in desktop, without any scrolls or zoom.

I use bootstrap 3 and my container  has `min-width:1220px`, if this will help.

Update: The problem is from table, when I remove table from the page, the website view is rendered as in desktop (with smaller text, etc). And this problem occurs only on iPhone.

Comment: Try removing `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: I've removed it firstly, this show it as in desktop but with horizontal scrolls

Comment: Then my suggestion is that you give all the widths,margins,paddings etc in %..

Comment: this will not be the same as in desktop, I just want to see it somehow like zoom out, something like small view of desktop

Comment: yes it will be...it will look same in both desktop as well as in mobile devices..

Comment: I tables in the page,even if when I use table-layout:fixed, the data is collapsed, so this is not what I want. I just needed the whole page to be zoomed out, This is done for other pages and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to setup the viewport to be the width you want it to display in mobile. For you, with your `min-width` value, you'll want something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1220">
```

Note that the content width changed from `device-width` to your width value. This will allow the scaling you want. Otherwise, the browser will try to assume some defaults and it will be too small for your site. Specifically, it will try 920px wide, which is why you get a horizontal scroll.

Comment: don't help :( this has the same result as with css, also the problem is only in iphone, on abdroid devices all is ok with my code

Comment: Do you have an example url or a fiddle or something to take a look at? Because likely if this doesn't help it means there is something in your CSS or code that is throwing off the viewport rendering

Comment: @FrontDev I don't see the modified meta viewport code on that page. Did you already remove it?

Comment: @FrontDev Ah, sorry, that was my bad. Remove the `, initial-scale=1`. That was a copy/paste error. That should get you fully zoomed out

Comment: you rock man!!! thanks a lot, have worked on this full 4 hours, you solved this in 15 min!!!! :****

Comment: Is there a way to use this for print too? when I try to print it cut the page. I want this to be rendered in print too.

Comment: @FrontDev Printing is a different sort of beast. I might ask a new question for that, but the only way I can think of is using `@media` queries for it.

Comment: Thanks have asked already here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29063886/print-meta-for-print-page