# Print: Meta for Print page

Tags: html, css, printing

I use this meta to show my desktop version in mobile.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=1220">`

Now I want this to be rendered in print too. When I want to print the page, in portrait version my screen is cutted of. Is there a meta for this in print? How can I zoom out my page for print too?

Related question for mobile is here [RWD: Show Desktop version in mobile minified, without horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051774/rwd-show-desktop-version-in-mobile-minified-without-horizontal-scroll)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    @media print{@page {size: landscape}}

    @page { size : portrait }
    @page rotated { size : landscape }
```

[stackoverflow -landscape printing from html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html)

[tutorialspoint - css paged media](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_paged_media.htm)