# Responsive: Open large desktop view in small desktops without scroll and @media

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need to open large screen view(e.g.screen width 1400px) in small screen . I had this problem for mobile, which was solved by using this meta `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1220">`. Related question [RWD: Show Desktop version in mobile minified, without horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051774/rwd-show-desktop-version-in-mobile-minified-without-horizontal-scroll)

I can't use @media for smaller desktops as client wants the same sizes and appearance as in large screens. So is there a way to use this meta not only for mobile devices but for desktops too or you can advise another way? Thanks!